# SQL Server 2012 removing duplicates with ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, partition, row-number

I've been trying to solve a problem with data duplication for a while now using `row_number()` and I just can't get it to work. I have a bunch of records, all for the same date but with different times so I only want the first 2 date instances for each day (each instance is effectively half a day), I can ignore the others.

The SQL below almost does what I want, but only gives me half the rows I'm expecting

```
SELECT
    Trade.tradedate AS TradeDate,
    Trade.status,
    contract.contract AS ContractID,
    'obsolete' AS ZainetRef,
    fee.feemode,
    position.counterparty,
    position.positiontype,
    Trade.cstcontractstart AS ContractStartDate, 
    Trade.cstcontractend AS ContractEndDate,
    contract.contracttype,
    CONVERT(INT, Trade.trade) AS TradeID,
    feetimeperiod.feetimeperiod,
    feetimeperiod.dbcolumn,
    feetimeperiod.dbvalue,
    (CONVERT(TIME, feetimeperiod.begtime)) AS TheTime,
    feetimeperiod.begtime AS FeeTimePeriodBeginTime,
    feetimeperiod.endtime AS FeeTimePeriodEndTime,
    loadshapeprofile.begtime AS StartDateTime,
    loadshapeprofile.endtime AS EndDateTime,
    loadshapeprofile.offset,
    loadshape.timeunit,
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) = 1 
          THEN 'D' 
       WHEN CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) > 1  
            AND CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) <= 31 
          THEN 'M' 
       WHEN CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) > 31 
            AND CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) <= 93 
          THEN 'Q'
       WHEN CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) > 93 
            AND CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) <= 183 
          THEN 'S'
       ELSE 'Y' 
    END AS BlockDescription,
    position.block,
    CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS FLOAT) * 24.0  AS HoursInPeriod,
    CAST((loadshapeprofile.endtime - loadshapeprofile.begtime) AS INT) AS Days,
    position.unit,
    ISNULL(fee.pricediff,0) AS GBPMWh,
    CASE
       WHEN loadshape.timeunit = 'HALFHOUR' 
          THEN ((loadshapeprofile.he1 + loadshapeprofile.he2 + loadshapeprofile.he3 + loadshapeprofile.he4 + loadshapeprofile.he5 + loadshapeprofile.he6 + loadshapeprofile.he7 + loadshapeprofile.he8 + loadshapeprofile.he9 + loadshapeprofile.he10 + loadshapeprofile.he11 + loadshapeprofile.he12 + loadshapeprofile.he13 + loadshapeprofile.he14 + loadshapeprofile.he15 + loadshapeprofile.he16 + loadshapeprofile.he17 + loadshapeprofile.he18 + loadshapeprofile.he19 + loadshapeprofile.he20 + loadshapeprofile.he21 + loadshapeprofile.he22 + loadshapeprofile.he23 + loadshapeprofile.he24 + loadshapeprofile.he25) * 0.5)/24
    ELSE  
        ((loadshapeprofile.he1 + loadshapeprofile.he2 + loadshapeprofile.he3  + loadshapeprofile.he4 + loadshapeprofile.he5 + loadshapeprofile.he6 + loadshapeprofile.he7 + loadshapeprofile.he8 + loadshapeprofile.he9 + loadshapeprofile.he10 + loadshapeprofile.he11 + loadshapeprofile.he12 + loadshapeprofile.he13 + loadshapeprofile.he14 + loadshapeprofile.he15 + loadshapeprofile.he16 + loadshapeprofile.he17 + loadshapeprofile.he18 + loadshapeprofile.he19 + loadshapeprofile.he20 + loadshapeprofile.he21  + loadshapeprofile.he22 + loadshapeprofile.he23 + loadshapeprofile.he24 + loadshapeprofile.he25) )/24
    END AS MW,
    CASE
       WHEN loadshape.timeunit = 'HALFHOUR' 
          THEN 
    ((loadshapeprofile.he1 
    + loadshapeprofile.he2 
    + loadshapeprofile.he3 
    + loadshapeprofile.he4 
    + loadshapeprofile.he5
    + loadshapeprofile.he6
    + loadshapeprofile.he7
    + loadshapeprofile.he8
    + loadshapeprofile.he9
    + loadshapeprofile.he10
    + loadshapeprofile.he11
    + loadshapeprofile.he12
    + loadshapeprofile.he13
    + loadshapeprofile.he14
    + loadshapeprofile.he15
    + loadshapeprofile.he16 
    + loadshapeprofile.he17
    + loadshapeprofile.he18
    + loadshapeprofile.he19
    + loadshapeprofile.he20
    + loadshapeprofile.he21 
    + loadshapeprofile.he22
    + loadshapeprofile.he23
    + loadshapeprofile.he24
    + loadshapeprofile.he25) * 0.5) 
    ELSE  
    ((loadshapeprofile.he1 
    + loadshapeprofile.he2 
    + loadshapeprofile.he3 
    + loadshapeprofile.he4 
    + loadshapeprofile.he5
    + loadshapeprofile.he6
    + loadshapeprofile.he7
    + loadshapeprofile.he8
    + loadshapeprofile.he9
    + loadshapeprofile.he10
    + loadshapeprofile.he11
    + loadshapeprofile.he12
    + loadshapeprofile.he13
    + loadshapeprofile.he14
    + loadshapeprofile.he15
    + loadshapeprofile.he16 
    + loadshapeprofile.he17
    + loadshapeprofile.he18
    + loadshapeprofile.he19
    + loadshapeprofile.he20
    + loadshapeprofile.he21 
    + loadshapeprofile.he22
    + loadshapeprofile.he23
    + loadshapeprofile.he24
    + loadshapeprofile.he25))
END AS MWh,
CASE
    WHEN loadshape.timeunit = 'HALFHOUR' THEN 
    ((loadshapeprofile.he1 
    + loadshapeprofile.he2 
    + loadshapeprofile.he3 
    + loadshapeprofile.he4 
    + loadshapeprofile.he5
    + loadshapeprofile.he6
    + loadshapeprofile.he7
    + loadshapeprofile.he8
    + loadshapeprofile.he9
    + loadshapeprofile.he10
    + loadshapeprofile.he11
    + loadshapeprofile.he12
    + loadshapeprofile.he13
    + loadshapeprofile.he14
    + loadshapeprofile.he15
    + loadshapeprofile.he16 
    + loadshapeprofile.he17
    + loadshapeprofile.he18
    + loadshapeprofile.he19
    + loadshapeprofile.he20
    + loadshapeprofile.he21 
    + loadshapeprofile.he22
    + loadshapeprofile.he23
    + loadshapeprofile.he24
    + loadshapeprofile.he25) * 0.5)  * ISNULL(fee.pricediff,0)
    ELSE  
    ((loadshapeprofile.he1 
    + loadshapeprofile.he2 
    + loadshapeprofile.he3 
    + loadshapeprofile.he4 
    + loadshapeprofile.he5
    + loadshapeprofile.he6
    + loadshapeprofile.he7
    + loadshapeprofile.he8
    + loadshapeprofile.he9
    + loadshapeprofile.he10
    + loadshapeprofile.he11
    + loadshapeprofile.he12
    + loadshapeprofile.he13
    + loadshapeprofile.he14
    + loadshapeprofile.he15
    + loadshapeprofile.he16 
    + loadshapeprofile.he17
    + loadshapeprofile.he18
    + loadshapeprofile.he19
    + loadshapeprofile.he20
    + loadshapeprofile.he21 
    + loadshapeprofile.he22
    + loadshapeprofile.he23
    + loadshapeprofile.he24
    + loadshapeprofile.he25) * ISNULL(fee.pricediff,0))
END AS BlockCost,
    loadshapeprofile.he1,   
    loadshapeprofile.he2,   
    loadshapeprofile.he3,   
    loadshapeprofile.he4,
    loadshapeprofile.he5,   
    loadshapeprofile.he6,   
    loadshapeprofile.he7,   
    loadshapeprofile.he8,   
    loadshapeprofile.he9,   
    loadshapeprofile.he10,  
    loadshapeprofile.he11,  
    loadshapeprofile.he12,  
    loadshapeprofile.he13,  
    loadshapeprofile.he14,  
    loadshapeprofile.he15,  
    loadshapeprofile.he16,  
    loadshapeprofile.he17,  
    loadshapeprofile.he18,  
    loadshapeprofile.he19,  
    loadshapeprofile.he20,  
    loadshapeprofile.he21,  
    loadshapeprofile.he22,  
    loadshapeprofile.he23,  
    loadshapeprofile.he24,  
    loadshapeprofile.he25   
from Trade
inner join position on trade.trade = position.trade
inner join contract on position.contract = contract.contract
inner join loadshape on position.loadshape = loadshape.loadshape
inner join loadshapeprofile on loadshape.loadshape = loadshapeprofile.loadshape 
inner join fee on position.position = fee.dbvalue 
inner join feetimeperiod on fee.feetimeperiod = feetimeperiod.feetimeperiod and feetimeperiod.dbvalue = position.position
where contract.contract = '1111111'
and position.loadshape is not null
and fee.dbcolumn = 'POSITION' 
and fee.feemethod = 'COMMODITY PRICE'
and (CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, feetimeperiod.begtime ) as decimal) = loadshapeprofile.offset)
and Trade.status = 'ACTIVE'
and trade.trade = 261333
and Trade.tradestatus IN ('FO Approval','TC Approval')
and feetimeperiod.feetimeperiod IN (select feetimeperiod from (select feetimeperiod, begtime, loadshapeprofile.offset, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by  CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.begtime), CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.endtime),loadshapeprofile.offset order by CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.begtime)) RowNumber from feetimeperiod) ftp where (ftp.RowNumber = 1 AND (CONVERT(date,ftp.begtime) =  CONVERT(date,loadshapeprofile.begtime) )) )
order by feetimeperiod.begtime
```

I'm aiming to get 2 rows for each FeeTimePeriodBeginTime (date), one row with offset 0 and another with offset 30 which effectively give me one day, but I'm really scratching my head (am i even going about this the right way ?)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get your point across ....

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not because the row_number, it is because you used row_number with "IN" condition. SQL Server removing duplicates with "IN" condition. If you want to see  duplicated lines you need to "JOIN" it.

Comment: but the inner subquery should remove any duplicates based on the over partition by clause, each feetimeperiod value will be unique for the "IN" condition

Answer (score 0):

Manged to figure it out myself in the end, I used a common table expression

```js
;WITH FeePeriod_CTE 
AS
(
 select feetimeperiod.feetimeperiod, 
  feetimeperiod.begtime, 
  feetimeperiod.endtime, 
  loadshapeprofile.offset, 
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.begtime),CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.endtime),loadshapeprofile.offset order by CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.begtime)) RowNumber 
  from trade
  inner join position on trade.trade = position.trade
  inner join contract on position.contract = contract.contract
  inner join loadshape on position.loadshape = loadshape.loadshape
  inner join loadshapeprofile on loadshape.loadshape = loadshapeprofile.loadshape 
  inner join fee on position.position = fee.dbvalue 
  inner join feetimeperiod on fee.feetimeperiod = feetimeperiod.feetimeperiod and feetimeperiod.dbvalue = position.position
  where contract.contract = '110156'
  and position.loadshape is not null
  and fee.dbcolumn = 'POSITION' 
  and fee.feemethod = 'COMMODITY PRICE'
  and (CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, feetimeperiod.begtime ) as decimal) = loadshapeprofile.offset)
  and Trade.status = 'ACTIVE'
  and trade.trade = 261333
  and Trade.tradestatus IN ('FO Approval','TC Approval')
  AND (CONVERT(date,feetimeperiod.begtime) =  CONVERT(date,loadshapeprofile.begtime) )
)
```

and then added this line in the WHERE clause

```js
and feetimeperiod.feetimeperiod IN (select feetimeperiod from FeePeriod_CTE where RowNumber = 1)
```

It now works perfectly